# Call asynchronous interdependent Redux Actions one after the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, async-await

In one of my React components, I have the following method:

```
  save() {
    var arrLength = this.state.arr.length;
    if(arrLength > 1) {

      var start = this.state.arr[arrLength-2];
      var end = this.state.arr[arrLength-1];


      this.props.updateItemAudio(start,end);
      this.props.saveItemToDisk();
      this.props.getNextItem();
    }
    else {
      console.log("Array not long enough yet");
    }
  }
```

The important bit is this:

```
  this.props.updateItemAudio(start,end);
  this.props.saveItemToDisk();
  this.props.getNextItem();
```

I need to wait for the first function call it finish, before executing the second, and it's the same thing with the third. How can I achieve this? I heard that there is this new `async / await syntax`, could i use that here somehow? I would prefer not to pass callback functions to each of these actions.

Edit: My methods **do not return promises**, they are normal Redux-actions.

Comment: Do those three functions return promises?

Comment: No, but good that you mention it, I edited my question. The three functions are just "normal" redux actions.

Comment: Or you could just execute them inside of those individual action creators, i.e. inside updateItemAudio action once it completes run saveItemToDisk and once that completes run getNextItem

Answer (score 0):

You could execute them one after another inside of the first action, i.e.:

```
updateItemAudio = async (start, end) => {

  return (dispatch) => {

     try {

       // updateItemAudio stuff...
       let resultTwo = await saveItemToDisk();
       let resultThree = await getNextItem();

       // now all 3 executed in order

     } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If yours methods return promise you can use:

```
async save() {
 await this.props.firstMethod();
 await this.props.secondMethod();
 await this.props.thisMethod();
}
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Your bundler or other task runner should transpile EcmaScript7 remember that

Comment: It does not return a promise, it is a plain redux action.

Comment: Then u can use this syntax in redux action:
 `myReduxAction() {
    return (dispatch) => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(); //call resolve if you get response or your action ended 
     })
 }
}`
Better syntax https://pastebin.com/7xkJieb4

Answer (score 0):

Pure redux does not allows you to dispatch an action after another action in a clean way.

I'll suggest to use 3rd party libraries for that, such as `redux-observable` or `redux-saga`. They fits perfect for your use case.

You can solve this problem using `redux-observable` in this way:

```
const myEpic = combineEpics(
  // listening to UPDATE_ITEM_AUDIO action type and dispatching saveItemToDisk() action after it
  action$ => action$.ofType(UPDATE_ITEM_AUDIO).map((action) => saveItemToDisk()),
  // the same as above, but listening for SAVE_ITEM_TO_DISK, and dispatching getNextItem() action
  action$ => action$.ofType(SAVE_ITEM_TO_DISK).map((action) => getNextItem())
)
```